# Size of a structure defined on other files (C)

Tags: c, header, structure, sizeof

On a project I'm working I need to know the size of a structure that is defined on a different file.

I tried to use sizeof(name_of_the_structure) but this didn't work because I can't include the other file in the current one.

The header file where the structure is defined has Include Guards and does't allow me to include it on the current file because it has already been included on other file.

I can manually place the size in code, but in the future if a change in the structure is needed I also need to change this.

What can I do in order to discover the structure size?

Thanks in advanced, best regards, Mauro.

Comment: Include guards should not cause a problem: if they don't let the header to be included, that's because it's **already** included.

Comment: Hello @H2CO3, yes it has already be included but not in the current file so when I try to compile I get 'error: 'ST_ContainerManagement' undeclared (first use in this function)'.

Comment: @userXXX "but not in the current file" - but yes. The point of include guards is that they prevent re-inclusion - they don't prevent including a file **at most once.** If the include guard is effective (i. e. it has just prevented the redefinition of stuff), then in the translation unit being compiled currently, everything's visible and fine.

Comment: @H2CO3 you're saying that it should be visible in the current file? but it has not been included in the current file, it has been included somewhere else in the code. The structure is define in "app_log.h" an instance of the structure is defined on "app_log.c" and I need to know the size of ST_ContainerManagement structure in SPI25VF064.c, though the file "app_log.h" has already been included somewhere else in the code. Regards, Mauro.

Comment: Yes, as @H2CO3 says, you can include `app_log.h` in `SPI25VF064.c` precisely because of include guards

Comment: let me guess : maybe you need write :`sizeof(struct struct_name)`

Comment: @LidongGuo: ... or being more precise by referring to one of the OP's comments: `sizeof(struct ST_ContainerManagement)`?

Answer (score 1):

If `struct ST_ContainerManagement` is declared in `app_log.h` then include `app_log.h` at the top of `SPI25VF064.c` and then in it's source do get the structures size.

```
#include "app_log.h"

...

size_t size_ST_ContainerManagement = sizeof(struct ST_ContainerManagement);
```